# Error on send Dialog: Attachment Unavailable

Tags: facebook, dialog

I'm trying to put a [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) on my page. But when I send it to any friend he gets the following message:

```
  Attachment Unavailable 
  The attachment source was deleted or the
  privacy settings on this attachment do not allow you to view it.
```

I have try both ways, in a direct URL and with the Javascript SDK.

Any ideas, why this is happening?

Comment: Could you please share some code?

Comment: @JoshuaCurci the code I use was all copied from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a look at this problem and it is all based on the person sending the message and their privacy settings. If the settings are custom then this error will come up but if it is public or friends then it will come up as normal.

Comment: if you are right. The problem is that in the dialg you cannot override the privacy settings. Where did you find that the problem was the privacy settings?

Comment: through trial and error...when i tested it found that it was the only constancy

Comment: Actually this problem is happening with my user. And I am already set to be Administrator of the app. So I think, maybe, maybe, it is a facebook bug. Another reason is that it was working at 1 PM and it isn't right now

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and I fixed it by pointing the 'link' attribute in FB.ui towards a non-HTTPS url. https:// triggered the error, http:// doesn't.

I know your message is old but I hope this can still help someone else.